# Apply skin to a control created programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, skinning

I am creating a Textbox in the codebehind of a page like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{  
      base.OnInit(e);
      TextBox test = new TextBox();
      test.SkinkId = "MySkin";
      placeHolder.Controls.Add(test);
}
```

and in my skin file I have this:

```
<asp:TextBox
    runat="server"
    SkinId = "MySkin"
    Width="400"
/>
```

Why is the skin not being applied to the control. If I declare the control in my aspx page it works ok, but if I try to do it programmatically it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558947/apply-skin-to-a-control-created-programatically

"The ASP.NET theming system has restrictions on when different theme information can be set. The Theme property can be set during PreInit. However StyleSheetTheme is processed at compilation time and thus cannot overriden programmatically in an event like PreInit."

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread. But i want to share what i had to do to in a similar situation. What helped me is to use ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this) after i created the control.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{  
    base.OnInit(e);

    TextBox test = new TextBox();
    test.SkinkId = "MySkin";
    test.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(this); // <--
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(test);
}
```

Comment: As an addition to Dbuggy's answer, this comes from msdn: "The ApplyStyleSheetSkin method sets style properties on the control based on skin properties defined in a theme directory. The skin applied is either the default skin for the control or the skin specified in the SkinID property. The ApplyStyleSheetSkin method is called by ASP.NET for declarative controls placed on a page. You must call the ApplyStyleSheetSkin method on any controls created programmatically at run time for style sheet skins to apply to the control. Theme skins are applied automatically."

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you place your code in the OnPreInit event? You might need to add it to the placeholder later, but you could create the control there.

Comment: According to Microsoft it should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx but I just tried with no luck :(

Comment: I just noticed that if I set the page's Theme property it works, but not the StyleSheetTheme...this must be a bug...